# How to prevent duplicate booking in calendar?

Tags: calendar

What is the best way to implement duplicate booking issues with calendar? We are on SP 2010. I tried couple of approach (like group settings) but that did not help. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this before. You need to use jquery and call REST services to call the Calendar after the form loses focus on the due date. The call will check to see if the request is unavailable.

Another way is to use the Resources content type, and have conference rooms or whatever you are trying to book as a resource that people can use. The form that you use will be able to check double booking...